# Uniqueness of Alfresco nodeREF

Tags: alfresco, guid, uuid, alfresco-share, uid

Are alfresco document node refs IDs, UIDs, UUIDs or GUIDs?

I haven't been successful in finding any documentation about this, but do see that AlfrescoOne has a GUID generator in one of its Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the are unique. Usually they look something like this workspace://SpacesStore/d0ab65f5-599c-439e-a87c-35eef61a0515

Comment: Yes it is, it is globally unique per repository. Repository meaning Alfresco databases, you can always use this property to reference the document no matter where it has been moved.

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco NodeRefs *must* be unique for the tenant they live in. By default, they are based on a sort of GUID, but they don't have to be. If you fire up your node browser, you'll see there are a handful of well-known noderefs, eg

- `workspace://SpacesStore/rendering_actions_space` -  /app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:rendering_actions
- `workspace://SpacesStore/publishing_root_space` -  /app:company_home/app:dictionary/app:publishing_root

Most though are things like `workspace://SpacesStore/88829143-8494-4cfe-99d6-6c7949aaa279`

Because those well-known noderefs will be present in every tenant in a system, you therefore know that noderefs only need be unique within a tenant, and not necessarily globally unique within a given install

Answer (score 0):

The GUID.generate() is used for all new node created. I had to deal with this matter when creating DataList entry programmatically, where each row has to have a unique identifier.

Alfresco, at least the version I have (4.2) is using the GUID.java class which internally use the `org.safehaus.uuid.uuidgenerator`

Altough by the specification the probability of a clash due to same GUID is actually extremely very low, you should have a look at that class from safehaus for gathering information about uniqueness if that ID.

**[UPDATE]**

However, just to enforce what other has said, which is NodeRef has to be unique for a tenant, it is worth to say that regardless the accuracy of GUID generator, there are some cases in which the same node guid could be found in more than one installation.

For example when developing an AMP which made use of [boostrap data](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Bootstrap_Data) for pre loading files into alfresco.
In that case, at least in Alfresco 4.2f, if you want to use the option `REPLACE_EXISTING` or `UPDATE_EXISTING` then you have to manually specify a guid for all the files you want to be uploaded or replaced at AMP. That GUID will then be assigned to the new node created.

So, if you upload your AMP in different Alfresco installation, then you will have the same GUID on each of them.

Comment: The default behaviour is to generate a GUID, but that's not the only option. You can also have special well known noderefs, such as `workspace://SpacesStore/rendering_actions_space` which aren't based on a GUID

Comment: Yes I know, but I suppose he is asking specifically about GUID node ref. I am writing more on this subject, in a second.